# How to run Kafka-connect-replicator in distributed mode?

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect

I want to replicate data from one system to another using confluent's replicator.I am using two Ubuntu 18.04 systems where one is acting as source and other as destination.

I tried to run kafka-connect-replicator in distributed mode where I changed the following configurations:

1. In confluent/etc/kafka/server.properties I made the following changes

```
SOURCE
> advertised.listeners=PLAINTEXT://source.ip:9092
DESTINATION
> advertised.listeners=PLAINTEXT://destination.ip:9092
```

2. In confluent/etc/kafka-connect-replicator/replicator.connect.distributed.properties I made the following changes

```
 - group.id=connect-replicator

group.id is same on source and destination system

SOURCE

 - bootstrap.servers=destination.ip:9092, source.ip:9092

DESTINATION

 - bootstrap.servers=destination.ip:9092, source.ip:9092
```

3. In confluent/etc/kafka-connect-replicator/quickstart-replicator.properties I changed the following configurations

SOURCE

```
name=replicator-source
connector.class=io.confluent.connect.replicator.ReplicatorSourceConnector
# source cluster connection info
src.kafka.bootstrap.servers=source.ip:9092
# Set to use direct connection to Zookeeper by Replicator on the source
src.zookeeper.connect=localhost:2181

# destination cluster connection info
dest.kafka.bootstrap.servers=destination.ip:9092
# Set to use direct connection to Zookeeper by Replicator on the destination
dest.zookeeper.connect=destination.ip:2181
# configure topics to replicate
topic.whitelist= test-topic
topic.rename.format=${topic}.replica
```

DESTINATION

```
name=replicator-source
connector.class=io.confluent.connect.replicator.ReplicatorSourceConnector
# source cluster connection info
src.kafka.bootstrap.servers=source.ip:9092
# Set to use direct connection to Zookeeper by Replicator on the source
src.zookeeper.connect=source.ip:2181

# destination cluster connection info
dest.kafka.bootstrap.servers=destination.ip:9092
# Set to use direct connection to Zookeeper by Replicator on the destination
dest.zookeeper.connect=destination.ip:2181
# configure topics to replicate
topic.whitelist= test-topic
topic.rename.format=${topic}.replica
```

And then I created topic in source system and launched the connector using the below command

`PATH_TO_CONFLUENT> sudo ./bin/connect-distributed ./etc/kafka-connect-replicator/replicator-connect-distributed.properties ./etc/kafka-connect-replicator/quickstart-replicator.properties`

After this I produced data in the topic from source system and try to consume in destination system with the topic name {topic}.replica but there is not topic present to consume from.

Answer (score 1):

It's not clear what errors you've having, but some notes.

1. `connect-distributed` only takes one property file, not two. You HTTP Post the Properties to the Connect Cluster as JSON, not load a properties file during cluster startup. The quickstart file is meant to be used for `connect-standalone`

The JSON would look like

```
{"name": "your-replicator-name", "config": {
  "src.kafka.bootstrap.servers": "...",
  ...
}
```

2. `./etc/kafka/connect-distributed.properties` should be a starting point for running any Connect or Replicator cluster in Distributed mode, although there may be similar configurations in `replicator-connect-distributed.properties`
3. `bootstrap.servers` should only ever point to a single cluster. The source and destination would be separated within `src.kafka.bootstrap.servers` and `dest.kafka.bootstrap.servers`

Comment: Yes, I figured that out. I'm finally able to replicate the data from source system to destination system. I'm creating the topic in source system and running the confluent replicator in destination system.